# how to make 1 foreignkey update on 2 primarykey one table in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

when I dd ($ unit price); going well but when you`enter code here` enter the database why only the last input is stored?

```
public function update_penawaran(Request $request,$id)
    {
        $harga_satuan = $request->input('harga_satuan');
        foreach ($request->input('harga_satuan') as $key => $hargasatu) {
          DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
          ->join('tbl_paket as b', 'a.id_paket', '=', 'b.id_paket')
          ->where('a.id_paket', $id)
          ->update([
              'b.status_paket' => $request->status_paket,
              'harga_satuan' => $harga_satuan[$key]
          ]);
        }
        // dd($harga_satuan);
        return redirect('/pesanan')->with('success','Berhasil Menambahkan Penawaran!');
    }
```

id_pesanan (primarykey)
id_paket (foreignkey)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ0as.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxp9K.png)

```
@foreach($pesanan as $p)


<tbody>
    <tr id="addRow" >
      <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;" >  {{$p->kode_bmn}}
      </td>

  <td class="col-xs-3" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->jenis_barang}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kuantitas}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->satuan_ukuran}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-5" style="text-align: center;">{{$p->kode_ruang}}
  </td>
  <td class="col-xs-3">
    <input class="form-control " name="harga_satuan[] " type="text" placeholder="Enter title" />
  </td>
</tr>


</tbody>
  @endforeach
```

how can this problem be resolved?

Comment: What do you intend to achieve with this code. whats really the problem with the code?

Comment: when inputting data is more than one in one field
only the last input is stored in the database @JuliusFasema

Comment: are you inserting or updating the record?

Comment: how do I get the 2 input into the database? @JuliusFasema

Comment: updating the record @JuliusFasema

Comment: which of these updated:  'b.status_paket' => $request->status_paket, 
              'harga_satuan' => $harga_satuan[$key]

Comment: both updated
status_paket can be updated

Comment: harga_satuan is only the last input stored @JuliusFasema

Comment: where do you have this $request->status_paket, on the form?

Comment: <input type="hidden" name="status_paket" value="2"> @JuliusFasema

Answer (score 0):

Change your controller code with this.

```
public function update_penawaran(Request $request,$id){
    $harga_satuan = $request->input('harga_satuan');
    foreach ($harga_satuan as $key => $hargasatu) {
        DB::table('tbl_pesanan as a')
            ->join('tbl_paket as b', 'a.id_paket', '=', 'b.id_paket')
            ->where('a.id_paket', $id)
            ->update([
                'b.status_paket' => $request->status_paket,
                'harga_satuan' => $hargasatu
            ]);
        }
    return redirect('/pesanan')->with('success','Berhasil Menambahkan Penawaran!');
}
```

I hope it'll resolve your problem

Comment: saved is still the last input